# How to make Two or more Nodes in D3.js using Force Directed Layout?

Tags: d3.js, nodes, force-layout, d3-force-directed

How can I make a basic connected graph (two or more nodes and a link connecting them for example) that use a force() layout? I just want to be able to drag a node and have the link adjust to stay connected as a node is being dragged. I  want also charge or positioning capabilities of force()  and double-click handling. Essentially I want every node to be "sticky". Nodes will only move when being dragged.

But is there a simple way to do this?  Like this sample that shows nodes and links -

http://djalmaweb.hyperphp.com/wordpress/time-graph-lines/image/

Is there a basic example somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Also, if "nodes will only move when being dragged" then you probably don't need a force layout — you just need a view that's aware of and can render nodes and their connections.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking for here, it would be great if you could post a fiddle or sample code. With the info you have, here is an example from Mike Bostock's samples that has a network chart with dragability and a forced layout.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Take a look and see if this will help you. Good luck.